# Rake not running properly in cronjob

Tags: ruby, cron, rake

I have a rake file, which can be executed successfully at command line. When I set a cronjob to run this rake file, the line "require 'json'" fails. My guess is that cronjob has a different env variable. It doesn't work when I tried to put "puts ENV" in the ruby script. So I'm wondering what I should do to check the different env variables and how to solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It might be how you're invoking it in cron. Here's what works for me:

```
cd /full/path/to/rails_root && /full/path/to/rake RAILS_ENV=production my:task
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have

```
require 'rubygems'
```

in your script? E.g. `irb` loads rubygems by default, while *normal* execution requires explicit *import*.

Comment: Yes I do have require 'rubygems'. If I run at commandline, rake data.rake, no problem. Error only happens at cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

First: `require "json"` is probably failing because rubygems isn't loaded.  You can probably fix that by either placing `require 'rubygems'` at the top, or by adding `RUBYOPT=rubygems` to the front of the cron job command line or to cron's environment (you can usually set environment variables in the crontab).

To answer your `ENV` debugging issue: is it possible that `puts ENV` isn't working because stdout is redirected somewhere you don't know about during the cron job (it certainly can't go to your terminal)?  You could try the following instead:

```
File.open('/tmp/debug_env', 'w') do |f|
  f.puts ENV.to_hash.inspect
end
```

And then take a look in `/tmp/debug_env` to see what's there.  Environment variables to especially look out for are `$USER`, `$GEM_HOME`, `$GEM_PATH`, `$RUBYOPT`.

Comment: First I do have rubygems loaded, second, I tried your advice adding RUBYOPT=rubygems to the front of cronjob, same error. I'll try the ENV debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Another manner of doing it: write a wrapper script to run from cron:
first line - load your .profile (or .bash_profile etc)
second line - run your rake script